# Logic check using any value from a list?

Tags: python, list, logic, if-statement

```
list = ["apples", "oranges", "jerky", "tofu"]

if "chew" in action and list[:] in action:
    print "Yum!"
else:
    print "Ew!"
```

How do I have a logic check where it checks for "chew" in action as well as ANY value in list? For example, I want to print "Yum!" whether action is "chew oranges" or "chew jerky".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use the builtin [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) function? The following seems quite Pythonic to me:

```
foods = ["apples", "oranges", "jerky", "tofu"]

if "chew" in action and any(f in action for f in foods):
    print "Yum!"
else:
    print "Ew!"
```

Of course, just searching for simple substrings may give some weird results. For instance `"jerkeyblahchew"` would still match the `"Yum!"` category. You'd probably want to split `action` into words, and look for food names that immediately follow `"chew"` (as @Peter Lyons suggests in his answer for the simple case where the first two words would be `"chew X"`).

Ignoring order, you could focus just on space-separated words (and further ignore capital/lowercase) by using something like the following:

```
foods = ["apples", "oranges", "jerky", "tofu"]
action_words = set(word.lower() for word in action.split())

if "chew" in action_words and any(f in action_words for f in foods):
    print "Yum!"
else:
    print "Ew!"
```

Comment: If I don't care about the order of the commands, would something like:

    split = action.split()
    if "chew" in split and any(f in split for f in foods):

work for separating action into words so that something like "horfdorftofuchew" would not work?

Comment: Sure, that would do. I've also edited my answer to include another alternative that also ignores case, if that makes sense for your situation.

Answer (score 4):

```
if "chew" in action and action.split()[1] in list:
    print "Yum!"
else:
    print "Ew!"
```

Comment: How would I have it so that it'll return True even if any of the foods in the list are in action.split()[0] rather than [1]?

Comment: Well, depending on exactly what you are trying to do you probably want to first parse action from a string into a list of words, and then maybe consider using a `set` and testing for `issubset`.  FYI don't name your variable `list`.  It shadows the built-in type and isn't meaningful.  Try `foods`.

Comment: @Peter:  Actually issubset won't work - `chew` isn't in the list of foods (so a set like ('chew', oranges') isn't a subset.  He could check if the length of the intersection of the two sets was > 0 though.

Comment: Yeah @Gerrat, I know.  The question isn't specific enough (or at least doesn't identify the larger goal he's trying to meet) to write a specific answer. Next step could be to add "chew" to the list and then use issubset, but there are many ways to do this, and definitely clearer ways to solve whatever it is TomKo is working on.

Answer (score 0):

First off, please don't use list as a variable name. It's a keyword in python

```
_list = ["apples", "oranges", "jerky", "tofu"]
bools = [True for a in action.split() if a in (_list + ["chew"])]
if True in bools:
    print "Yum!"
else:
    print "Ew!"
```

Answer (score 0):

`x in y` means "look at each of the elements of `y` in turn; is any of them equal to `x`?" So the logic is obviously not right: `list` (a bad idea for a variable name, BTW, since that's the name of the type) is a list of strings, and `action` is a string - the elements of a string are letters, and no letter can be equal to a list of strings.

Comment: Oh, that's helpful. Clarifies just why I've been told to put the action into words using .split()

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like you want to do some set operation here (intersection).

Assuming `action` is a basestring containing words:

```
foods = set(["apples", "oranges", "jerky", "tofu"])
actionWords = set(action.split())

if "chew" in action and foods & actionWords:
    print "Yum!"
else:
    print "Ew!"
```

the `&` operator on a set stands for intersection, see [python doc](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=intersection#set.intersection).